# How to add a character to the beginning of every word in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string for example

```
some_string = "Hello there! How are you?"
```

I want to add a character to the beginning of every word such that the final string looks like

```
some_string = "#0Hello #0there! #0How #0are #0you?"
```

So I did something like this

```
temp_array = []

some_string.split(" ").forEach(function(item, index) {
    temp_array.push("#0" + item)

})

console.log(temp_array.join(" "))
```

Is there any one liner to do this operation without creating an intermediary `temp_array`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could map the splitted strings and add the prefix. Then join the array.

```js
var string = "Hello there! How are you?",
    result = string.split(' ').map(s => '#0' + s).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the regex `(\b\w+\b)`, along with [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) to append your string to each new word

`\b` matches a word boundry

`\w+` matches one or more word characters in your string

`$1` in the `.replace()` is a backrefence to capture group 1

```js
let string = "Hello there! How are you?";
let regex = /(\b\w+\b)/g;

console.log(string.replace(regex, '#0$1'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **map()**, it will directly return a new array :

```
let result = some_string.split(" ").map((item) => {
    return "#0" + item;
}).join(" ");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with regex:

```js
let some_string = "Hello there! How are you?"

some_string = '#0' + some_string.replace(/\s/g, ' #0');
console.log(some_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is regex. There is already regex soln give. However can be simplified.

```js
var some_string = "Hello there! How are you?"

console.log(some_string.replace(/[^\s]+/g, m => `#0${m}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const src = "floral print";
const res = src.replace(/\b([^\s]+)\b/g, '+$1');
```

result is +floral +print
useful for mysql fulltext boolean mode search.